# Can dragging actions replace the need for pan buttons in a map?

Tags: map-ui, panning

Can the mouse click and drag functionality on map interface (such as Google Maps) substitute the need for pan (`<`, `>`, `^`, `v`) buttons?

[image: pan zoom buttons courtesy of Google Maps]

Note: I have revised this question to exclude discussion on zoom since double clicking only allows zooming in (refer to answer by Riche Design).

Comment: Why does it have to be either-or? Just offer both, your users will thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think most novice user audiences will require the interface. I still don't really know how to zoom out with click and drag.

Comment: for instance, you click and drag up, that zooms in, and dragging down will zoom out.

Comment: Is that not for panning up and down?

Comment: the thing is mechanics are limited, and they where more limited time ago. I remember using this same technic to zoom in and out, but I can't remember where

Comment: Thanks for your input, I agree with you. That leaves panning unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that they can substitute the action quite well, but not the need itself. Need is something you feel.

But since users may be already used to that mechanic, you will have to add a legend to the map/application telling how to use it.